# current-menu-item class is not added

Tags: menus, navigation

Trying to style the active class of my navigation menu on my one-page theme, I have noticed that wordpress does not assign the current-menu-item class.
Why is this happening? Can you help me?

It is just a one-page theme, so the links in the page menu point to the sections on the same page.

in my header.php (child-theme):

```php
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
    'menu_class' => 'nav__menu js-nav__menu',
    ) );
    ?>
```

in my `function.php`(child-theme):

```
<?php



/* Copiado del parent theme, y eliminado algunas partes que hasta el momento no necesitaba */
/* Comparar con functions.pho del parent theme para ver cuales */
if ( ! function_exists( 'cafecoders_child_setup' ) ) :
    /**
     * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
     *
     * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
     * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
     * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
     */
    function cafecoders_child_setup() {

        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            // el menu-1 está en el parent theme, aquí en el child-theme me creo uno nuevo
            'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Main menu cafecoders-child', 'cafecoders-child' ),
        ) );



        /**
         * Add support for core custom logo.
         * Personalizar > Identidad del Sitio
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo
         */
        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
            'height'      => 250, //dimensiones sugeridas en Personalizar > Identidad del Sitio > Seleccionar el logotipo
            'width'       => 250, //dimensiones sugeridas en Personalizar > Identidad del Sitio > Seleccionar el logotipo
            'flex-width'  => true,
            'flex-height' => true,
        ) );



    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cafecoders_child_setup' );


// Esta funcion añade la clase "nav__item" a los li del menu (menu-2)
function atg_menu_classes($classes, $item, $args) {
    if($args->theme_location == 'menu-2') {
      $classes[] = 'nav__item';
    }
    return $classes;
  }
  add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'atg_menu_classes', 1, 3);




// Habilitar Wordpress para para subir a Medios files de tipo SVG
// con esto no hace falta instalar plugins
  function add_file_types_to_uploads($file_types){
    $new_filetypes = array();
    $new_filetypes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $file_types = array_merge($file_types, $new_filetypes );
    return $file_types;
    }
    add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_file_types_to_uploads');






function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

 $parent_style = 'cafecoders-parent-style'; // Estos son los estilos del tema padre recogidos por el tema hijo.

 wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'cafecoders-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/styles/style.min.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));

 wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,400i,700&display=swap', false );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'load-font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css' );

 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'personal-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/javascript.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );






// Wordpress agrega en atuomatico la clase "home" al body
// Aquí como robarsela!
add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
    if (in_array('home', $classes)) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('home', $classes)] );
    }
  return $classes;
});


/**
 * CHANGE CLASSES
 * 
 * In the the_custom_logo(); output
 * custom-logo-link > nav__logo
 */
function helpwp_custom_logo_output( $html ) {
    $html = str_replace('custom-logo-link', 'nav__logo', $html );
    return $html;
}
add_filter('get_custom_logo', 'helpwp_custom_logo_output', 10);









// Agregar la clase "active" a "current-menu-item"
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

function.php (parent-theme):

```
<?php
/**
 * cafecoders functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package cafecoders
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'cafecoders_setup' ) ) :
    /**
     * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
     *
     * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
     * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
     * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
     */
    function cafecoders_setup() {
        /*
         * Make theme available for translation.
         * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
         * If you're building a theme based on cafecoders, use a find and replace
         * to change 'cafecoders' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
         */
        load_theme_textdomain( 'cafecoders', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
         *
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'cafecoders' ),
        ) );

        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
            'search-form',
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption',
        ) );

        // Set up the WordPress core custom background feature.
        add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'cafecoders_custom_background_args', array(
            'default-color' => 'ffffff',
            'default-image' => '',
        ) ) );

        // Add theme support for selective refresh for widgets.
        add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

        /**
         * Add support for core custom logo.
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo
         */
        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
            'height'      => 250,
            'width'       => 250,
            'flex-width'  => true,
            'flex-height' => true,
        ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cafecoders_setup' );

/**
 * Set the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 */
function cafecoders_content_width() {
    // This variable is intended to be overruled from themes.
    // Open WPCS issue: {@link https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/1043}.
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.PrefixAllGlobals.NonPrefixedVariableFound
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'cafecoders_content_width', 640 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cafecoders_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#registering-a-sidebar
 */
function cafecoders_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'cafecoders' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'cafecoders' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'cafecoders_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function cafecoders_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cafecoders-parent-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cafecoders-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cafecoders-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cafecoders_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-functions.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
if ( defined( 'JETPACK__VERSION' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `cafecoders_child_setup` function is missing some code, could you show us the whole function? Also, could we see the output generated by `wp_nav_menu`?

Comment: I just update the question, so you can see complete function.php in the child-theme (the one i'm using) and the function.php in the parent-theme. Basically i'm copying from the function.php in the parent theme what i need, and i'm pasting it in the function.php in the child theme, and adding to this file the new settings.

Comment: If this is indeed a one-page site, your links will technically always be the current-item. If you want to update on scroll/click, you'll need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: So the question is...for what current-menu-item is, and when Wordpress add it to the items in the navigation?..